# "Grown Graphic" filters - legit or fakes?

Tags: filters

I went to buy a Nikon lens here in China for my D5100 and the salesman tried to talk me into buying a protective filter by "Grown Graphic".

My scam-radar lit up for two reasons:

- this is China
- there is a *crown* on the front but the name is spelled *Grown*

Google turns up precious few results for this name, and those results are generally for shady-looking webstores. No big name places.

Is this a legit filter or should I steer clear?

[image]

Comment: Crown Graphic was the name of a large-format press camera, BTW. http://www.largeformatphotography.info/cameras/pacemaker/

Comment: Not buying something you've never heard of that salespeople try and talk you into is a good strategy for life in general!

Comment: I'm surprised there's not a picture of a clown on the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to vote scam.

Reason being "Crown Glass" is a [specific type of optical glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_glass_(optics)). But not a brand... someone with only limited english proficiency trying to rip off a well known brand is possibly likely to end up with exactly what you see.

Comment: Indeed. That is one of many Nikon shops all clustered together. Sadly, it was recommended to me by a local whom I trust. I will have a chance to swing by again in a few weeks and will politely but directly share my findings with the salesperson and give him a chance to explain himself. I'll update my original post accordingly with his reply, if only for the comedy value and as a warning to others...